# Load large file into auto-partitioned database partitioned on KDB by monthly instead of daily

Tags: kdb

I have a very large text file (> 100 GB) that I want to load into a partitioned splayed KDB db.

The following guide seems like what I wanted to use https://code.kx.com/v2/kb/loading-from-large-files/

The following code from the guide does partitioning by the date.

```
$ cat fs.q
\d .Q

/ extension of .Q.dpft to separate table name & data
/  and allow append or overwrite
/  pass table data in t, table name in n, : or , in g
k)dpfgnt:{[d;p;f;g;n;t]if[~&/qm'r:+en[d]t;'`unmappable];
{[d;g;t;i;x]@[d;x;g;t[x]i]}[d:par[d;p;n];g;r;<r f]'!r;
@[;f;`p#]@[d;`.d;:;f,r@&~f=r:!r];n}

/ generalization of .Q.dpfnt to auto-partition and save a multi-partition table
/  pass table data in t, table name in n, name of column to partition on in c
k)dcfgnt:{[d;c;f;g;n;t]*p dpfgnt[d;;f;g;n]'?[t;;0b;()]',:'(=;c;)'p:?[;();();c]?[t;();1b;(,c)!,c]}

\d .

r:flip`date`open`high`low`close`volume`sym!("DFFFFIS";",")0:
w:.Q.dcfgnt[`:db;`date;`sym;,;`stats]
.Q.fs[w r@]`:file.csv
```

However, I want to auto-partition by the month or the year of the date instead (I don't wan't to transform the date column itself, i just want the data to be partitioned by month or year instead). How do I modify the above code to do this? I tried changing `date to`mm$date instead, but that didn't work.

Comment: Could you provide some details on the data you are working with? Is it daily aggregates? How many distinct syms would there be, a magnitude estimate would suffice? Over what timespan does the data cover? It would be a simple case to adjust this to a monthly write down function, but it would assume that you have monthly aggregated data. If your data isn't aggregated monthly then this operation would involve having to sort each month aggregate to ensure that a parted attribute can be placed on the table and that the HDB will be performant

Comment: its not monthly aggregate. the data is still pretty much daily snapshot. Timespan could be like 20 years. Analysis is generally done over say a month of data at a time. Although daily analysis is possible too. @CallumBiggs

Comment: What's the driving force behind monthly partitioning? You can easily perform analysis on monthly data from a daily partitioned database. The reverse is not true. Pulling daily data will be expensive

Comment: "You can easily perform analysis on monthly data from a daily partitioned database."

Ok I wasn't sure if that was the case. Thanks for clarification, maybe daily is the way to go.

Comment: To give some more details, the data is about 1 billion rows in a text file. The rows are about 6 columns, 2 of them being the date and sym column. There's about a million distinct syms. Is the .Q.dcfgnt code above the optimal way of loading this into kdb? @CallumBiggs

Comment: You can just adjust the worry to select over a range of dates to and then perform the monthly aggregation. It may be require some in memory sorting depending on the nature of the analysis performed

Comment: It should perform reasonably well. But you could create a subset of the text file and then run some tests. You could then get an idea of the total time required and memory consumption in the process

Comment: how does the sorting for the parted attribute work anyways? Suppose im inserting a row for a specific date. Does it have to load all other previously inserted rows for that specific date partition into memory to figure out where to insert the new row? I'm noticing some significant slowdown in insert throughput after around 25 million entries inserted. @CallumBiggs

Comment: so i let the above code run the import on a 1 billion row text file...woke up the next after like 12 hours, and its only managed to import 100 million rows.... i was hoping this process would be blazing fast...this seems really slow @CallumBiggs

Comment: Hi Peter, are you able to identify the bottle neck? Consider the CPU of the machine, the read/write capabilities of the storage medium in question etc. You could adjust the code used so that the writedown itself is multithreaded over columns. Finally if you could split the source file up into distinct date ranges then you could use multiple processes. Remember there is no free lunch, kdb will spend some time writing to disk to make sure future queries are very fast. Feel free to message me for follow up and I'll try to respond in my free time.

Comment: I have a different question. I tried a different data set with the same loading method. However I got a u-fail error.. Why would this happen? I was under the impression that the above loading method would rearrange the rows so that the sym column can be applied with a parted attribute. I've tried this with a tiny dataset and can see that the rows got rearranged so that sym column is parted, but I can't figure out why with the larger dataset, I'm getting the u-fail error. @CallumBiggs